# Intercepting window.external.notify call from javascript in objective C

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview

I need to intercept a javascript call to window.external.notify which is returning a security token string that I need to get into my objective C code.  The javascript is being executed in a UIWebView.  The script there looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    try{
        window.external.notify('{<extremely long dictionary as a JSON string>}');
    }
    catch(err){
        alert("Error ACS50021: window.external.notify is not registered.");
    }
</script>
```

I need to somehow get the JSON dictionary into a string in objective C.  I've tried going through the method here: http://www.stevesaxon.me/posts/2011/window-external-notify-in-ios-uiwebview/; but it just seems to interfere with the rendering of the html/javascript page and also not capture the string (I don't have a handy acs identifier to check for to know I'm intercepting the right call).  Other similar questions have been asked, but I haven't been able to get any working, many seem extremely hackish, and they are usually quite out of date.  I've tried accessing the webview's html content, but the token isn't present there, because it's only sent through window.external.notify, which errors out with the alert that it isn't registered.

I know there's now a native JS->objC bridge in iOS 7, and I only need to support iOS 7+, but I've never used it and I can't seem to get that up and running either.  It also appears to be mainly for having your own JS source files as part of your app, and not for communicating with a server through a UIWebView, but if I'm wrong about that, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [method](http://www.stevesaxon.me/posts/2011/window-external-notify-in-ios-uiwebview/).Here the page is redirected and the token is loaded using receive data method.